# Move image from left to right and right to left in iphone

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

```
- (void)moveImage:(UIImageView *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
            curve:(int)curve x:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y
{
    // Setup the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    // The transform matrix
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y);
    image.transform = transform;

    // Commit the changes
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    UIImageView *imageToMove = 
    [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];
    imageToMove.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20);
    [self.view addSubview:imageToMove];

    // Move the image
    [self moveImage:imageToMove duration:3.0 
              curve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear x:50.0 y:50.0];  

}
```

I have tried this one.It works fine at one time from left to right.But i need to move the image from left and right to left repeatedly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

y dont  you create a NSTimer that repeatedly calls the function every 5 secs(where 5 is the time reqd to move from left to right) and then this function will check.

```
if(image.origin.x< 0 )
     //move image to right
 else if(image.origin.x > 320)
     // move image to left.
```

Either user **`NSTimer`** or in your move function call a **`[self performSelector:];`**

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:timeDuration
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         [iVBackgroundImg setFrame:YOUR_FRAME];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```