# Move image from left to right in iPhone as circular and Infinite animation (like an advertisement)

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

I'm having difficulty moving an image from left to right.
Now i have a situation when i have an infinite animation but it just replaces the current image to another.

here's my code:

```
-(void)startAnimationTest
{
   image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic_1.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic_2.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic_3.png"], nil];
   [image setAnimationDuration:1];
   image.animationDuration = 4;
   [image startAnimating];

}
```

thank you,

Eliza

Comment: your code does not even try to move the image (what class is that even) - just initializes a set of variables.

Comment: right i am new to iphone and i will be happy for a good advice.
maybe you have a good tutorial or can give me an example?

Comment: Similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811597/move-image-from-left-to-right-and-right-to-left-in-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the images to a scroll view and then animating scrollview on the basis of its content offset. See the sample code attached. Make sure of add a nstimer to call the function repeatdly.

```
- (void) animateScrollView: (id) sender
{
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
     contentOffset.x +=3;
     [scrollView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:NO];
     [UIView commitAnimations];
     if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == (scrollView.bounds.size.width * 5)) {
         scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.bounds.origin.y);
     }
}
```

set timer as follows:

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: .03
                                 target: self
                               selector: @selector(animateScrollView:)
                               userInfo: nil
                                repeats: YES];
```

thats it. Hope it helps.